# How to back up using snapshots

Tags: google-cloud-platform, backup, google-compute-engine, snapshot

I chose a snapshot as a way to backup the VM(google compute engine).

I know that snapshots are incremental and automatically compressed. 
So I will take a snapshot every day at the appointed time. 
And I want to delete the snapshots that are older than 60 days.

Question
Will 60-day snapshots (full snapshots with all data) be combined with 59-day snapshots (incremental snapshots)?

Answer (score 1):

> Question Will 60-day snapshots (full snapshots with all data) be
>   combined with 59-day snapshots (incremental snapshots)?

Yes. The consistency of all snapshots will be maintained when you delete any snapshot including the oldest one.

Technically, nothing is combined, each snapshot is just a list of pointers to stored data blocks. When you delete the oldest snapshot any data in that snapshot that has been overwritten in the next newer snapshot will be released (deleted). The list of blocks in the 60th snapshot will be merged into the 59th snapshot. The 59th snapshot now represents the entire disk volume.

Answer (score 0):

Each snapshot will be incremental. You can have a better understanding of the procedure if you check the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#permissions-required-for-this-task).

Basically this is how it works.

[image: Snapshot]